# symmetric groups and cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

Are all the symmetric groups cyclic groups?

I know that by definition a cyclic group is a group that is generated by a single element. But if I've got a symmetric group like for example $H=\langle(2\ 1\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)(7\ 8\ 10\ 9) \rangle$ is it cyclic? I mean is it generated by one element or two?
*($H$ is a subgroup of $S_{10}$)

Comment: No, $S_3$ is not cyclic because it is not even abelian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your group $H$ is cyclic since it is generated by one element. When you ask if all "symmetric groups" are cyclic groups, however, by the usual definition the answer is no. $S_2$ is cyclic, but $S_n$ for $n\geq 3$ are nonabelian and hence not cyclic. These are all of the symmetric groups.

It seems you are talking about *subgroups* of symmetric groups though, and the answer is still no. Besides the group itself, you can take $\langle (12),(34)\rangle$ in $S_4$. This is isomorphic to the Klein $4$-group and hence is not cyclic. I suspect that most subgroups of the symmetric groups for $n\geq 5$ are not cyclic, but I won't make such a bold claim without proof.